# Powershell copy a column from a csv file and paste into the first row of another csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file named "final results.csv", there is a header row and some data. The header data are "Alias" with underscores, for example User_Name, User_Age, User_firstN, User_LastN

I have another csv file named "header names.csv" where the actual name of the headers are stored. It has one single column, so the data looks like this.

```
Header
User Name
User Age
First Name
Last Name
```

The goal is to extract the header actual names from the 2nd file, and paste them into the first row of the first file. So the first file ("final results.csv") has a header with actual header names as opposed to aliases.

How do I achived this using Powershell? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the columns in the same positional order horisontally in the CSV as they are vertically in the text file? And are all column names *only* replacing underscores with spaces? If the latter is the case, there's a much easier way to do this - I'll pose an example once I see your reply.

Comment: Order is the same. Name is not necessarily the same as alias without the underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right you have a CSV with header names you want to replace. Currently they are `X_X` and you want to replace them with `X X`. You can do it easily with `Select-Object` and calculated properties. Now if you have a lot of headers that could be a lot of manual work. Here's a way to take the headers and dynamically build the calculated properties.

Demo data.

```
# first file
$csv = @"
User_Name,User_Age,First_Name,Last_Name
ab,20,a,b
cd,21,c,d
ef,22,e,f
"@ |ConvertFrom-Csv

# second file
$headers = @"
header
User Name
User Age
First Name
Last Name
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Build the calculated properties

```
$SelectProps = @($headers | ForEach-Object {
    @{n=$_.header;e={$($_.header.Replace('_',' '))}}
})
```

Here's what that should look like at this point

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                          
n                              User Name                                                                                                                                                      
e                              User_Name                                                                                                                                                      
n                              User Age                                                                                                                                                       
e                              User_Age                                                                                                                                                       
n                              First Name                                                                                                                                                     
e                              First_Name                                                                                                                                                     
n                              Last Name                                                                                                                                                      
e                              Last_Name
```

Now we simply replace them.

```
$csv | Select-Object $SelectProps

User Name User Age First Name Last Name
--------- -------- ---------- ---------
ab        20       a          b        
cd        21       c          d        
ef        22       e          f
```

Making your code

```
$csv = Import-Csv "final results.csv"

$headers = Import-Csv "header names.csv"

$SelectProps =  @($headers | ForEach-Object {
    @{n=$_.header;e=($_.header.Replace(' ','_'))}
})

$csv | Select-Object $SelectProps |
    Export-Csv -Path "final results.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

But you can also just replace the first line with `Get-Content`, `Set-Content`, and `-join`

```
$headers = Import-Csv "header names.csv"

Set-Content -Value $(
    $headers.header -join ','
    Get-Content "final results.csv" | Select-Object -Skip 1
) "final results.csv"

Import-Csv "final results.csv"

User Name User Age First Name Last Name
--------- -------- ---------- ---------
ab        20       a          b
cd        21       c          d
ef        22       e          f
```

Comment: Thanks Doug. I have accepted another shorter solution. But this looks good, I could definitely use this for other scenarios.

Comment: That’s no problem. Maybe I should’ve led with the second solution. It wasn’t 100% clear the columns were in the same order of the headers so I focused on a solution that it wouldn’t matter what order they were in. Have a great day

Comment: Thanks, I see you also have the shorter version. I think your solution might help more people as I realized even for me the order isn't always the same, so this solution is more helpful and I will need to figure out my code based on this one you provided.  Thanks!

Comment: Just tried on my code, I have an updated header file with field name and field alias on two separate columns as a mapping file, your solution is perfect!!! I only needed to update this @{n=$_.name;e=($_.alias)} as I have the mapping. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me I wouldn't bother reading in the CSV I'd simply work with it as text.  All you're really doing is replacing the first line with the correct headers.  Assuming the file isn't more complicated than described something like below should work:

```
# Get the headers:
$Headers = (Get-Content <2ndFile> | Select-Object -Skip 1) -join ','

# Combine with the CSV file skip the first row to accomplish the replace:
$Headers, @(Get-Content <1stFile> | Select-Object -Skip 1) | Set-Content <NewCsv>
```

Obviously, adjust file names as needed...

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charm, and so short, great solution!  I saw you fixed the ), I was going to add it but had to step out.

Comment: Thanks, but I am confused. Why would the headers be in a different order.  Relying on string replacement doesn't satisfy the question, at least as it was stated. ie "First Name" maps to "User_FirstN" NOT "First_Name" as implied and effectively hardcoded in the other solution.  That said, this could be almost as short without ingesting CSV data as objects.  I'd probably just create a hash to resolve/relate one version of a header to the other.  If there is a reliable assumption that the headers are the same except for the underscore I can still think concise eloquent solutions...